# Cannot find sensible way to fix Nvidia GPU poorly configured power management for Linux laptop

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, power-management

My laptop (a Dell Inspiron 7577) has an Nvidia GTX 1060, and I configured the laptop to dual boot Ubuntu in addition to the Windows that came with it.

Edit: Here's more information about my system. I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and my GPU is the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2. My Nvidia driver number is 525.147.05. My Linux kernel version is 5.15.0-88-generic.

I've noticed that if I boot into Ubuntu and run a graphics heavy process while on battery, the laptop would shut itself down within seconds. This didn't happen on AC power, and it wouldn't happen if I booted into Windows and ran a graphics heavy process there, even when running on the battery. When crashing, the GPU did not have a chance to heat up significantly. The GPU does not overheat anyway under heavy usage, on AC power.

Later I determined that the GPU was using close to its maximum power limit of 60W and entered power state P3, maybe P2, before it crashed, while on Windows it would not exceed 18W and power state P5 while on battery. So I've basically determined that the power draw must've exceeded the battery's spec, causing perhaps an undervolting that made the laptop shut down.

I was wondering, what is the proper way to fix this issue? I've noticed that the Nvidia driver did modify the Enforced Power Limit the moment I switch to battery power, but it only enforces a maximum of 55W which is still too close to the normal maximum of 60W. And I could not find a way to change this 55W number despite a lot of Google search.

The only idea I currently have is perhaps some really hacky scripting to automatically run `nvidia-smi -pl`. Making sure this reliably runs on boot, on wake from sleep, and every time I plug or unplug the laptop, sounds like a nightmare. Is there not a more canonical way to configure the GPU power management?

Comment: Tangentially, I was just wondering: `nvidia-smi -pl` tells me that I should set persistence mode, but I thought `nvidia-persistenced` already achieves the same effect? And wouldn't persistence waste a lot of power when the laptop is suspended?

Comment: Probably, yeah. But I have greatly enjoyed using Linux as my daily driver, only switching to Windows when I needed to use Windows-specific application (and cursing at Windows while at it). Also, I often use the laptop for deep learning experiments, I haven't tried to set up a Linux VM inside Windows but my hunch is that the kind of deep integration for CUDA is harder to do and my workload would run much less efficiently.

Comment: Wait, if I use dual booting, wouldn't Linux effectively become the host machine when I boot into Linux? Then I think I get the shutdown on battery, whether I use a heavy GPU process on the host Linux, or if I then started a VM Windows and run a heavy GPU process inside. I currently don't use any VM.

Comment: Dual boot only uses one OS at a time

Comment: Which Ubuntu release/version? Which Nvidia drivers version? Please [edit] the question accordingly. Furthermore I strongly suggest not engaging with unhelpful comments suggesting VMs.

Comment: Thanks, I've added more system information.

Comment: Any reason for using a 3+ years old release (and with the oldest kernel available)? Newer hardware works best with the newest release/kernel. Additionally differences between Windows and Ubuntu are to be expected even under the (Ubuntu's) best conditions: In Windows the system toggles seamlessly the iGPU and the dGPU (Nvidia) depending on the software requests while in Ubuntu typically it's one or the other.

Comment: I've simply been using the computer for much more than 3 years by now. I do apply updates when possible, but updates to major releases and kernel updates run the risk of breaking things such as the Nvidia driver, and I cannot afford disrupting my work. But I do agree 5.4 is old now, I've went ahead and spent about an hour binary searching for the highest kernel version I can use without extensive troubleshooting. Now I am running kernel 5.9.16-050916-generic.

Comment: You can simply install the HWE kernel - https://askubuntu.com/a/1314330/1210606 - instead of manually installing versions from who knows where (BTW, I think the one you installed is out of support). At least in that regard you'll be closer to the current release.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was originally getting the kernel from the Mainline Kernels installer, and 5.15 didn't work with that. Unfortunately, the kernel version seems to have no bearing on the GPU power draw issue.

Comment: The power issue is a matter of perception. As explained already, in Windows you're mostly using the "power saving" profile (iGPU) only toggling to the Nvidia card if there's software specifically demanding it, while in Linux you're using it always until you change the profile and reboot. Does the problem of shutting down still occurs?

Comment: I test by running CUDA kernels, so I can guarantee that the discrete GPU was under heavy load when I tested both operating systems. I haven't noticed a shutdown in either OS from doing more daily tasks like video playback. Though I don't play graphic intensive games so I can't say whether those cause shutdown.  But anyway I most certainly had been using the Nvidia card in Windows during my test, regardless of the dual GPU features. At present, yes I still experience shutdown on Ubuntu when running CUDA kernels.